# Proof: "Each vertex belongs to exactly one connected component"

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

On this Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29 they state "Each vertex belongs to exactly one connected component".

How can this be proven formally?

Comment: Might want to show that being in a connected component is an equivalence relationship,  therefore it partitions the graph into equivalence classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a vertex $v$ belonged to two strongly connected components $A$ and $B$, then all vertices in component $A$ would be mutually reachable to each vertex in component $B$, because you could just go from any vertex in $A$, pass through $v$ and continue to $B$.

If this were the case, component $A$ and component $B$ would actually form ONE component, since all vertices in $A \cup B$ are mutually reachable.

Comment: So this means that the A must be either exactly equal to B, or have nothing in common?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate it!